# Get Google Document createdTime in NodeJS - Google Docs API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

To get the `createdTime` for a file (video, audio, etc..), `Google.files.get({...})` can be used, but it does not seem like the `DocumentId` and `fileId` is the same.

Using Google Docs in NodeJS (googleapis, docs v1), how does a person get the `createdTime` for a Google Doc.

Comment: What makes you think it is not the same? How do you retrieve the `DocumentId`?

Comment: welcome to SO. You might want to edit your question to explain your problem in more detail. The subject is about createdTime, but your question is talking about documentId. Ideally show your code along with the both the expected result and the actual result.

Comment: @ziganotschka - I retrieve the documentId from the URL when opening a Google Document. The reason why I think its not the same, is the error message is:

File not found: DOCUMENTID 

errors:
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'notFound',
       message:
        'File not found: DOCUMENTID.',
       locationType: 'parameter',
       location: 'fileId' } ] }

(The actual Id removed)

Comment: Your document URL should lokk like `https://docs.google.com/document/d/XXXXXX/edit`, whereby `XXXXXX` is the file Id. Can you confirm that this is the way how you retrieve the fileId?

Comment: @ziganotschka, here the log:
googleDocsUrl: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zlmZZiEz4NigIg3lYxFETZB0K2Zc3kzSy_JM6ZXiq9I/edit

googleDocFileId: 1zlmZZiEz4NigIg3lYxFETZB0K2Zc3kzSy_JM6ZXiq9I

googleDocFileId is stripped out from the url.

Comment: And this is the code snippet that attempts to load the doc:

 const fileRes = await GOOGLE_DRIVE.files.get({            
            'fileId': googleDocFileId,
            'fields': 'lastModifyingUser,properties,mimeType,description,version,createdTime,size,imageMediaMetadata,videoMediaMetadata,appProperties'
        });

Comment: The same id is also used to read the Document Content, which works fine:

const googleDocRes = await GOOGLE_DOCS.documents.get({
    documentId: googleDocFileId
  });

Comment: So only problem I see with your code snippet is that it should be `fileId` and not `'fileId'` - same for `fields`. If this does not solve the issue - please dit your quetion providing your full relevant code, inlcuding the definition of `GOOGLE_DRIVE`. Also, please test with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) to narrow down error sources.

Comment: @ziganotschka thanks for your help, the issue was supportsAllDrives : true, by default this is false, and the file(s) are located in a Google Shared Drive.

Comment: Yes, that's a common error source - I did not realize that your file was on a shared drive. I am glad you found the reason!